# Parsing an Array passed as an Object to a C# UDF for Azure Stream Analytics

Tags: c#, json, azure-stream-analytics

Here is a part of the JSON file that's relevant. I am trying the pass Values to a user defined script for processing

```
{
"FragCount": 63,
"ValueMapping": 7,
"DataType": 19,
"BurstId": 85,
"SensorNodeId": "bd8e8077",
"Values": [
  23,
  -3,
  20,
  31,
  51,
  -3,
  -14,
  -4,
  47,
  31,
  52,
  -3,
  2,
  -3,
  42,
  31,
  49,
  -3,
  -18,
  -4,
  -10,
  30,
  47,
  -3,
  -29,
  -4,
  55,
  31,
  27,
  -3,
  -24,
  -4,
  11,
  31,
  -32,
  -4,
  -38,
  -4,
  -18,
  30,
  -20,
  -4,
  -76,
  -4,
  -42,
  30,
  -59,
  -4,
  -81,
  -4,
  45,
  31,
  -79,
  -4,
  -75,
  -4,
  19,
  31,
  -93,
  -4,
  -99,
  -4,
  -40,
  30,
  -122,
  -4,
  -90,
  -4,
  -70,
  30,
  -128,
  -4,
  -92,
  -4,
  -112,
  30,
  119,
  -4,
  -91,
  -4,
  -46,
  30,
  120,
  -4,
  -49,
  -4,
  -61,
  30,
  87,
  -4,
  -43,
  -4,
  -27,
  30,
  61,
  -4
],
```

The Stream Analytics Query looks like this

```
WITH ReaderQuery AS (
SELECT
    *
FROM
    [IoT-Hub]
)


SELECT
       SensorNodeId AS SensorID,
       FragCount AS FragCount,
       ValueMapping AS ValueMapping,
       DataType AS DataType,
       BurstId AS BurstId,
       udf.FFTDecompressor_Class1_FFTDecomFunc(try_cast([Values] as Array)) AS [Values],
       MeasurementId AS MeasurementId

  INTO
       [FFT]
  FROM
       ReaderQuery
       WHERE ( DataType = 19 )
```

This is the user defined function. **I really can't figure out how I could parse Values in Object b into an integer list or array for processing.**

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.IO;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Text;

   namespace FFTDecompressor
   {
    public class Class1
     {


    // Public static function
    public static String FFTDecomFunc(Object b)
    {
        //int[] a = Array.ConvertAll<object, int>(b.ToArray(), (o) => (int)o);
        //List<int> a = b.Split(',').Select(s => int.Parse(s)).ToList();
        List<int> FFTList = new List<int>();
        String DecompressedValues = null;

        for (int i = 0; i < a.Count; i++)
        {

            if (i == 0)
            {
                FFTList.Add(BitConverter.ToUInt16(new[] { Convert.ToByte(a[i]), Convert.ToByte(a[i +1]), }, 0));
                FFTList.ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(x));
                i++;
            }
            else
            {
                if (a[i] == -128)
                {
                    FFTList.Add(BitConverter.ToUInt16(new[] { Convert.ToByte(a[i + 1]), 
                    Convert.ToByte(a[i + 2]), }, 0));
                    i += 2;
                }
                else
                {

                    if (FFTList.Count == 1)
                    {
                        FFTList.Add(FFTList[0] + a[i]);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        FFTList.Add(FFTList[(FFTList.Count - 1)] + a[i]);
                    }
                }

            }

        }

        /*
        for (int i = 0; i < FFTList.Count; ++i)
        {
            FFTList[i] /= 100;
        }
        */
        DecompressedValues = string.Join(",", FFTList);  


        return DecompressedValues;
    }
   }
  }
```

Comment: What is object b? is it a json object? Do you know the structure of the object? If yes, you could deserialize the object. Here is the link to the microsoft dacs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-how-to

Comment: I'm passing Values from the json file.

Comment: have you tried to cast the object to an array? `var stringArray = b as string[];` afterwards you could parse through the list with linq `var a = stringArray.Select(x => Int32.Parse(x)).ToList();`

Comment: With that I get this error:
Error : **User Error** UDF : {"Message":"Error while running UDF function 'fftdecompressor_class1_fftdecomfunc' with input '([ 40, 0, -40, 20, -6, -14, 14, -14, 46, 18, -64, -128, -125, 0, -128, 0, 0, -128, -87, 0, 7, -128, 0, 0, -128, -95, 0, -128, 0, 0, -128, -99, 2, -128, -74, 3, -128, 0, 0, -128, -47, 1, -128, 0, 0, -128, -24, 1, -72, -128, 0, 0, -128, -62, 0, -128, 0, 0, -128, 20, 1, -128, -119, 0, -128, 0, 0, 79, -79, 14, 0, -14, 74, -74, 34, -34, 0])'. Exception 'Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: source'.","Source":{"Name":"","Type":null},"Type":115}

Comment: Maybe the brackets are getting in the way?

Comment: Looks like json for me => [1,2,3,4,5]. I would try `var a = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<int>>(b);`

Comment: `JsonConvert` is in library https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/

Comment: *sigh* Because the custom code shares context with Azure Stream Analytics engine, custom code can't reference anything that has a conflicting namespace/dll_name with Azure Stream Analytics code. For example, you can't reference Newtonsoft Json.

Comment: I'm not familiar with azure stream analytics. If you can use microsoft references, you could use `using System.Web.Script.Serialization;` or `using System.Runtime.Serialization;` If you cannot use one of these references you have to do it yourself by converting it from string. What do you get if you cast it to a string? `var a = b as string;`

Comment: string myObjectString = b.ToString();  List<int> a = myObjectString.Split(',').Select(x => int.Parse(x.Trim())).ToList();           
Error : **User Error** UDF : {"Message":"Error while running UDF function 'fftdecompressor_class1_fftdecomfunc' with input '([ 40, 0, -40, 20, -6, -14, 14, -14, 46, 18, -64, -128, -125, 0, -128, 0, 0, -128, -87, 0, 7, -128, 0, 0, -128, -95, 0, -128, 0, 0, -128, -99, 2, -128, -74, 3, -128, 0, 0, -128, -47])'.        I get Exception 'Input string was not in a correct format.'.","Source":{"Name":"","Type":null},"Type":115}

Comment: we are coming close to the end. :-) Try this `string myObjectString = b.ToString(); List<int> a = myObjectString.Replace("[","").Replace("]","").Split(',').Where(m => int.TryParse(m.Trim(), out int n)).Select(x => int.Parse(x.Trim())).ToList();`

Comment: Unfortunately I only get emptiness from that. The result of string myObjectString = b.ToString(); seems to be System.Object[] instead of a string which is perhaps the problem

Comment: if its no string but object array then try this `var myObjArray = b as object[]; List<int> a = myObjArray.Where(m => int.TryParse(m.ToString().Trim(), out int n)).Select(x => int.Parse(x.ToString().Trim())).ToList();`

Comment: I think it works now, the next problem is perhaps in my byte conversions
Error : **User Error** UDF : {"Message":"Error while running UDF function 'fftdecompressor_class1_fftdecomfunc' with input '([ 40, 0, -40, 20, -6, -14, 14, -14, 46, 18, -64, -128, -125, 0, -128, 0, 0, -128, -87, 0, 7, -128, 0, 0, -128, -95, 0, -128, 0, 0, -128, -99, 2, -128, -74, 3, -128, 0, 0, -128, -47, 1, -128, 0, 0, -128, -24, 1, -72, -128, 0, 0, -128, -62, 0, -128, 0, 0, -128, 20, 1, -128])'. Exception 'Value was either too large or too small for an unsigned byte.'.","Source":{"Name":"","Type":null},"Type":115}

Comment: Thanks a million!

Comment: `Value was either too large or too small for an unsigned byte.` => use `BitConverter.ToInt16` instead of `BitConverter.ToUInt16`

Comment: Strange, that did not help.

Comment: I discovered the problem. I can't feed Convert.ToByte negative signed numbers for some damn reason, it says so in the specs. So I created another array that converts a's content into unsigned bytes,  byte[] unsignedBytes = a.Select(sb => (byte)sb).ToArray(); and then feed that to BitConverter.ToInt16. Thanks for your help, you are a real life saver!

Answer (score 0):

Given you know that your input is an array, you don't need to cast it to type Array. Here is what you can do instead. You query could be:

```
SELECT udf.sampleASAproject_Class1_sampleudf([Values]) from Input
```

And my example C# UDF (Codebehind in my case) returns converts the array to Int64 type and returns the first value:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace sampleASAproject
{
    public class Class1
    {
        // Public static function
        public static Int64 sampleudf(Object[] data)
        {
            Int64[] arrayInteger = data.Cast<Int64>().ToArray();
            return arrayInteger[0];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Exception 'Specified cast is not valid.'.","Source":{"Name":"","Type":null},"Type":115}